# Perl EV module create periodic events

Tags: perl

I'm using EV module to create a timed events that will run indefinitely in a defined time interval, here is my code with defined intervals.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;
use feature 'say';
use EV;
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

my $one_sec = EV::timer 1,1, sub {
   say "(1s)  Periodic event at ", localtime(EV::now)->hms;
};

my $five_sec = EV::timer 5, 5, sub {
  say "(5s)  Periodic event at ", localtime(EV::now)->hms;
};

EV::run;
```

I'm trying to define these functions dynamically from hash reference, by looping through it to create these functions.

```
my $hash = {
    'one_sec'  => '1',
    'five_sec' => '5',
};
```

I have used foreach to loop through the hash.

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$hash )
{

        my $key = EV::timer $hash->{$key},$hash->{$key}, sub {
        say "($hash->{$key})  Periodic event at ", localtime(EV::now)->hms;
        };

        EV::run;      
}
```

It works, but only for the first iteration, I'm not sure why is that?

Your thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: Move the `EV::run` out of the `foreach` loop. If that starts an event loop, it will never break the `foreach` and gets stuck in the first iteration.

Comment: If I do, it won't run at all :(

Comment: Oh. I just see someting. You do have `strict`, right? You are assigning the return value of `EV::timer` to `$key`, which only exists in the loop. You also redefine `$key` by using `my`, although it's already there. From skimming the docs I am not sure if the timer object needs to be kept in scope, or if it internally has its own copy. But I believe that if it goes out of scope, it will _forget_ about it. That's why it doesn't run in that environment. Let me write an answer, though that is only guess-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is not tested.

---

There are two things wrong with your code:

First, you are starting the event loop in the body of your `foreach` loop, which will make it run within the first iteration of the `foreach`. It will then get stuck there, and only one of the timers will be created. To fix that, the `EV::run` needs to be moved to outside of the `foreach`.

However, it will then not do anything at all. That's because the event-loop has nothing to do. That is because you are defining your `EV::timer` objects lexically within the body of the `foreach`. Once one iteration is done, that variable (`$key`) will go out of scope, destroying the timer object. When it's done creating both, it will just run an empty event-loop. In addition to that, you redefined `$key`, which was already the `"one_sec"` or `"five_sec"` string that comes out of the hash.

Instead, you need to put the event objects somewhere that's outside of the loop, too (because each block creates a lexical scope in Perl when you use `my`, which is a feature).

You should also use more speaking variable names so you don't get confused.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;
use feature 'say';
use EV;
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

my $config = {         # was $hash
    'one_sec'  => '1',
    'five_sec' => '5',
}

my $timers;
foreach my $key ( keys %$config ) {
    $timers->{$key} = EV::timer $config->{$key},$config->{$key}, sub {
        say "($config->{$key})  Periodic event at ", localtime(EV::now)->hms;
    };
}

EV::run;
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but still struggling, here is my code  [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/bYb52Cfs)

Comment: @deano You are missing `{}` around `$key`. There should be error messages if you have `strict` and `warnings`. Read them! ;) What you are doing now is trying to assign to a method call. If you do `$timers->$key` it will try to run a function with the name of the value of `$key` on the object `$timers`. Since that is an unblessed hash, it will die with _Can't call a method on an unblessed reference..._.